# 4 is an element in the following set:

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

> A) $\{x \in  \mathbb{Z} \mid 4 < x < 10\}$
>
> B) $\{x \in  \mathbb{Z}  \mid x \text{ is the square of an integer}\}$
>
> C) $\{4, \{4\}\}$
>
> D) $\{\{4\},\{\{4\}\}\}$
>
> E) $\{\{\{4\}\}\}$

Here are the answers I came up with. I am pretty confident about A-C, but I'm not sure about D and E.

A: $4$ is not an element because $x < 4$. False

B: This can be true, only if the integer being squared is $2$. True

C: This contained $4$ and the subset $\{4\}$, so True.

D: Both of these are subsets, so False.

E: This is only a subset, which is not the same as $4$. False.

Could someone confirm my logic on this is correct?

Comment: Your reasoning about A) should be: $4$ is not an element of that set because $4<4<10$ is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answers to all of them are correct, but $D$ and $E$ are poorly expressed.  For $D$ you might say $\{4\}$ and $\{\{4\}\}$ are elements but $4$ is not.

Comment: I see. Thank you! @RossMillikan

Answer (score 3):

All of your answers are absolutely correct. {4} but not 4, is an element of {{4}}. Similarly, {{4}} is an element of {{{4}}}.

Comment: Excellent. Thank you!

Comment: In D, $\{4\}$ is an *element* of the set $\{\{4\}, \{\{4\}\}$ rather than a subset.  A similar comment applies to E.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig You are right thank you.